# Javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

So i have this javascript piece that has two buttons to go to full screen and one to exit full screen. I want to make it so that if I am not in full screen the button says go to full screen and when i am in full screen the button says exit full screen...
So basically that i only need one button to enter/exit full screen.

```
<html>
<head>  
<script>
function launchFullscreen(element) {
if(element.requestFullScreen) {
element.requestFullScreen();
} else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
}

function cancelFullscreen() {
if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
document.cancelFullScreen();
} else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
document.mozCancelFullScreen();
} else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);">Launch Fullscreen</button>

<button onclick="cancelFullscreen();">Hide Fullscreen</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you'll need to assign an ID to the button.

```
<button id="fsBtn" onclick=launchFullscreen(document.documentElement)>Enter Full Screen</button>
```

When the button has been pressed, you'll want to change the button's innerHTML value inside the "fullscreen()" function:

```
document.getElementById("fsBtn").innerHTML = "Exit Full Screen";
```

You can also change a button's onclick value:

```
document.getElementById("fsBtn").onclick = cancelFullscreen;
```

Comment: @adamjcSweet this works BUT. only once. There is one button how i wanted and it says enter full screen, when i click it, it goes into full screen and says exit full screen, and when i click that it exits full screen, and wont go back into full screen. Thanks though... ill work on it a bit more but if you know a  quick solution let me know.

Comment: In the cancelFullscreen function you will want to have similar code, that changes the buttons innerHTML to "Enter Full Screen" and assign the onclick value to the enterFullscreen function.

Comment: I added this.... works + custom images too.                                                      var screenFull = false;
var img = new Image('button').src = ".//images/up_full.fw.png"; 
document.getElementById('button').src = ".//images/up_full.fw.png";
function togle() {

if (screenFull) {
cancelFullscreen(); 
document.getElementById('button').src = ".//images/up_full.fw.png";
screenFull = false;
}
else {
launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);
document.getElementById('button').src = ".//images/down_full.fw.png"; 

screenFull = true;

Answer (score 1):

Add id to button and just toggle button
ex:

```
function launchFullscreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    //hide full screen button
    this.style.display ='none'
    //show exit button
    document.getElementById("btn_cancel_fullscreen").style.display ='inline'  

}

function cancelFullscreen() {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
     //hide cancel full screen button
    this.style.display ='none'
    //show full screen button
    document.getElementById("btn_fullscreen").style.display ='inline'  
}
<button id='btn_fullscreen' onclick="launchFullscreen(document....)"> Fullscreen</button>
<button id='btn_cancel_fullscreen' style='display:none' onclick="cancelFullscreen();">Hide Fullscreen</button>
```